# swift api json numeric unit comma control

Tags: json, swift

```
func getKoreacountryChart() {
    AF.request("https://api.corona-19.kr/korea/country/new/?", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                
                let result = response.data
                
                if result != nil {
                    let json = JSON(result!)
                    
                    let seoul = json["seoul"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let busan = json["busan"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let daegu = json["daegu"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let incheon = json["incheon"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let gwangju = json["gwangju"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let daejeon = json["daejeon"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let ulsan = json["ulsan"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let sejong = json["sejong"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let gyeonggi = json["gyeonggi"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let gangwon = json["gangwon"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let chungbuk = json["chungbuk"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let chungnam = json["chungnam"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let jeonbuk = json["jeonbuk"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let jeonnam = json["jeonnam"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let gyeongbuk = json["gyeongbuk"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let gyeongnam = json["gyeongnam"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let jeju = json["jeju"]["totalCase"].intValue
                    let quarantine = json["quarantine"]["totalCase"].intValue


                    
                    self.KoreaCountryData = KCountryData(seoul: seoul, busan: busan, daegu: daegu, incheon: incheon, gwangju: gwangju, daejeon: daejeon, ulsan: ulsan, sejong: sejong, gyeonggi: gyeonggi, gangwon: gangwon, chungbuk: chungbuk, chungnam: chungnam, jeonbuk: jeonbuk, jeonnam: jeonnam, gyeongbuk: gyeongbuk, gyeongnam: gyeongnam, jeju: jeju, quarantine: quarantine)
                } else {
                    self.KoreaCountryData = KcountrytestDate
                }
            }

struct KCountryData {

let seoul: Int
let busan: Int
let daegu: Int
let incheon: Int
let gwangju: Int
let daejeon: Int
let ulsan: Int
let sejong: Int
let gyeonggi: Int
let gangwon: Int
let chungbuk: Int
let chungnam: Int
let jeonbuk: Int
let jeonnam: Int
let gyeongbuk: Int
let gyeongnam: Int
let jeju: Int
let quarantine: Int
}
```

I'm using Swiftui to create a covid app.

---

I got a json form from api and I was pasing

---

"totalCase": "26,732",
"recovered": "24,395", The json format contains a comma, so it is not accurate output.

---

ex) totalCase: 26, recovered: 24 I want to erase the comma and express all the numbers.

---

{
"resultCode": "0",
"resultMessage": "정상 처리되었습니다.",
"korea": {
"countryName": "합계",
"newCase": "97",
"totalCase": "26,732",
"recovered": "24,395",
"death": "468",
"percentage": "51.56",
"newCcase": "79",
"newFcase": "18"
},
"seoul": {
"countryName": "서울",
"newCase": "25",
"totalCase": "6,081",
"recovered": "5,500",
"death": "78",
"percentage": "62.47",
"newCcase": "20",
"newFcase": "5"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your string remove the commas (thousand separator) and the enclosing quotes as well. One you have done that you can decode your json string and treat the properties as integers. You can still use SwiftyJSON if you would like to or using `Codable` as shown bellow:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let resultCode: Int
    let resultMessage: String
    let korea, seoul: Country
}
```

---

```
struct Country: Codable {
    let countryName: String
    let newCase, totalCase, recovered, death: Int
    let percentage: Double
    let newCcase, newFcase: Int
}
```

---

```
if let result = response.data {
    do {
        let cleaned = result.replacingOccurrences(of: ",(?=\\d{3})", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
            .replacingOccurrences(of: #"\"(\d+)\""#, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
            .replacingOccurrences(of: #"\"(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})\""#, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
        print(cleaned)  // { "resultCode": 0, "resultMessage": "정상 처리되었습니다.", "korea": { "countryName": "합계", "newCase": 97, "totalCase": 26732, "recovered": 24395, "death": 468, "percentage": 51.56, "newCcase": 79, "newFcase": 18 }, "seoul": { "countryName": "서울", "newCase": 25, "totalCase": 6081, "recovered": 5500, "death": 78, "percentage": 62.47, "newCcase": 20, "newFcase": 5 }}
        let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(cleaned.utf8))
        print(root)  // "Root(resultCode: 0, resultMessage: "정상 처리되었습니다.", korea: __lldb_expr_11.Country(countryName: "합계", newCase: 97, totalCase: 26732, recovered: 24395, death: 468, percentage: 51.56, newCcase: 79, newFcase: 18), seoul: __lldb_expr_11.Country(countryName: "서울", newCase: 25, totalCase: 6081, recovered: 5500, death: 78, percentage: 62.47, newCcase: 20, newFcase: 5))\n"
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number formatter to convert this format to an int

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
```

Example

```
let string = "6,081"
if let value = numberFormatter.number(from: string)?.intValue {
    print(value)
}
```